# How can I close all dataframes that I've opened using the variable explorer?

Tags: python, spyder

In the process of writing code using python and pandas, I have opened many dataframes to inspect their contents by double clicking on their object names in the variable explorer. I was wondering if there is an option to "Close all", instead of "X"-ing out of each one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment, sorry.